# JERSEY : Error Trace : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entity input stream has already been closed

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I am working with Jersey 2.x.

Following is my controller

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getUser(@PathParam("id") int userId, @Context ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) {


        ContainerRequestContext requestContext = logRequest(containerRequestContext);

        //To further operations using requestContext

}
```

Following is my method inside the same controller class to record request

```
private ContainerRequestContext logRequest(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {

        JSONObject requestData = new JSONObject();
        try {

            Map bm = null;
            ContainerRequest cr = (ContainerRequest) requestContext;

            cr.bufferEntity();

            bm = cr.readEntity(Map.class);

            if (!String.valueOf(bm).equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                requestData.put("parameters", bm.toString());
            }

            requestData.put("uri", requestContext.getUriInfo().getRequestUri());
            requestData.put("ClientIp", requestContext.getProperty("requesterIp"));
            requestContext.setProperty("requestData", requestData);

        } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException | ProcessingException ex) {
            //Logging

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //Logging
        }
        return requestContext;
    }
```

As you can see I am using `bufferEntity()` to read ContainerRequestContext multiple times.

Still when I deploy my API on my server.

I am facing this error :

```
Error Trace : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entity input stream has already been closed.
```

What I am doing wrong here.
I will be thankful if somebody could explain me this behavior.

Comment: Probably because Jersey reads the stream before calling the resource method. You might want to look into using a [Filter](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html) instead, which is called before the resource method.

Comment: Probably because Jersey reads the stream before calling the resource method.
Sir , could you please explain a bit more, I want to understand this behavior , and you are absolutely right , earlier I have used this method in my filter , there I did not faced this issue. In my new project I moved this section of code to my controller level.

Comment: Because before Jersey can call your resource method, it needs to read the stream so that it can pass the entity to your method when it calls it. Even if you don't have an entity parameter, it appears Jersey still reads the stream.

Comment: Also you are using a GET. Is there even a body for this request?

Comment: Sir I am getting this exception for all the methods , GET ,PUT,POST.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar requirement and the way I've worked around this issue was by kind of "cloning" the request entity, with a help of Apache Commons' IOUtils  like the code snippet below:

```
//--- Create a new InputStream with the original entity ---//
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(requestContext.getEntityStream(), baos);
InputStream originalEntity = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));

//--- Reasign the original entity to Request Context ---//
requestContext.setEntityStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));

//--- From this point onwards, you can do whatever you want with the original request entity ---//

. . .

//--- In my case, I am working with JsonObject as below (try/catch ommited for brevity) ---//
JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(originalEntity);
JsonObject requestEntity = jsonReader.readObject();

. . .
```