# Not able to deserialize nested JSON array Spring Resttemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-resttemplate

I am not able to deserialize nested JSON array from response JSON using Spring Rest template.

JSON response which I am consuming is as follows

```
[
  {
    "creationTime": "2023-01-13",
    "code": "456",
    "cid": "123",
    "priority": "CRITICAL",
    "reviewDate": null,
    "systemCall": [
      {
        "creationTime": "2023-01-13",
        "status": null,
        "id": "787878",
        "modificationTime": "2023-01-13",
        "creatorId": "ABC"
      },
      {
        "creationTime": "2023-01-14",
        "status": null,
        "id": "787879",
        "modificationTime": "2023-01-14",
        "creatorId": "DEF"
      }
    ],
    level: "1"
  }
]
```

And My model classes as follows

```
public class Resolution {
    private String creationTime;
    private String code;
    private String cid;
    private String priority;
    private String reviewDate
    private List<SystemCallVo> systemCall;
    private String level;

    public Resolution(){
    } 
    
    //Getters and  Settrs
}

public class SystemCallVo {
    private String creationTime;
    private String status;
    private String id;
    private String modificationTime;
    private String creatorId;
   
    public SystemCallVo(){
    } 
    //Getters and  Setters
}

public class ResolutionVo extends Resolution{
    public ResolutionVo(){
    }   
}
```

I am calling my endpoint using rest template as follows.

```
ResponseEntity<List<ResolutionVo>> response = this.restTemplateConfig.restTemplate().exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<ResolutionVo>>() {
            }, new Object[0]);
```

Problem is List systemCall object is always null in response received through resttemplate even though  systemCall attribute is present in JSON whenever I hit endpoint through swagger.

Comment: are you sure key name is systemCall? Did you try running api from postman and getting same json response with same parameters that is being called from code using RestTemplate?

Comment: yes key name is systemCall and yes I am getting same json response with same parameters that is being called from code using RestTemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a defect in RestTemplate.exchange that prevents the deserialisation of even moderately complex JSON objects.

Read the response as a String and then deserialise to `List<ResolutionVo>` with an `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` instance as follows:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = this.restTemplateConfig.restTemplate().exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class, new Object[0]);
String body = response.getBody();
List<ResolutionVo> value = objectMapper.readValue(body, new TypeReference<List<ResolutionVo>>() {});
```

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823501/unable-to-read-application-json-message-in-response-output/51926122#51926122) is a related issue.

Comment: Interesting . Let me try this